# How to save the state of several EditTexts (to avoid user's mobile rotation) which were created on run time on a button press?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

My app is taking a number input from an EditText when user presses "OKAY" button. Then some EditTexts are created based on that input number. But when user rotates the screen the newly/dynamically created EditTexts get removed which I want to be saved when user rotates the screen.

I used `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to save the EditTexts' state but it didn't work(app crashes on phone rotation). May be, I couldn't use these methods in a right way.

I am giving my xml and java code:

My xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter No of EditText:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtNoCreate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="No of EditText"
            android:inputType="number"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OKAY"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#EDE9E9">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnrDynamicEditTextHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

My java code:

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout lnrDynamicEditTextHolder;
    private EditText edtNoCreate;
    private Button btnCreate;

    List<EditText> allEditText = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lnrDynamicEditTextHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrDynamicEditTextHolder);
        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        edtNoCreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNoCreate);

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()>0 && parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString())!=0) {
                        if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()==0){
                            edtNoCreate.setError("This Item Cannot be Empty");
                            return;
                        }
                        allEditText.clear();
                        lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.removeAllViews();

                        int length = parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString());

                        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
                            EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                            editText.setId(i+1);
                            editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            allEditText.add(editText);
                            lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    edtNoCreate.setError("This Item Cannot be Empty");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        int mViewsCount = 0;
        for(EditText view : allEditText)
        {
            savedInstanceState.putInt("mViewId_" + mViewsCount, view.getId());
            mViewsCount++;
        }

        savedInstanceState.putInt("mViewsCount", mViewsCount);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        int mViewsCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("mViewsCount");;
        for(int i = 0; i <= mViewsCount; i++)
        {
            EditText view = allEditText.get(i);

            int viewId = savedInstanceState.getInt("mViewId_" + i);
            view.setId(viewId);

            mViewsCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Rene Ferrari*'s answer is almost correct. But, if we use **value 0** as an **ID** of **EditText**, then ***"Invalid ID 0x00000000"*** is printed in Logcat.

Besides, we need not to use **allIds** (**ArrayList**) and we need not to handle it in **onSaveInstanceState**.

Instead, we can simply save the size of **allEditText** (**List**) in **onSaveInstanceState**.

However, the final code is here:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout lnrDynamicEditTextHolder;
    private EditText edtNoCreate;
    private Button btnCreate;

    List<EditText> allEditText = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lnrDynamicEditTextHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrDynamicEditTextHolder);
        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        edtNoCreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNoCreate);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int sizeOfEditText = savedInstanceState.getInt("NUMBER_OF_EDITTEXT");

            for (int i=1;i<=sizeOfEditText;i++){
                EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(i);
                editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                allEditText.add(editText);
                lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);
            }
        }

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()>0 && parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString())!=0) {
                        if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()==0){
                            edtNoCreate.setError("This Item Cannot be Empty");
                            return;
                        }
                        allEditText.clear();
                        lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.removeAllViews();

                        int length = parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString());

                        for (int i=1;i<=length;i++){
                            EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                            editText.setId(i);
                            editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            allEditText.add(editText);
                            lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    edtNoCreate.setError("This Item Cannot be Empty");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("NUMBER_OF_EDITTEXT", allEditText.size());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add these line in your manifest under you activity declaration, to prevent recreation on configuration change.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActiyvity"
      android:configChanges="orientation">
```

for more details read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the existing answers using ViewModels and manually handling the configChange do help.

However personally I would be cautious with setting the configChanges in the manifest. Even the documentation warns:

> Caution: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much
>   more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does
>   not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be
>   considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a
>   configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.

Using a ViewModel would really be a great way for general handling of orientation change. However one could argue that it does not fit well in your scenario since you are dynamically creating Views and the ViewModel should not know about those Views.

Anyway here is how I would handle it in your situation:

- First of all save the id's of your `EditText`'s in an `ArrayList<Int>`
- When adding a new EditText just set your id to your id-List's size and add an element to the list with the value of it's size
- Then in onSaveInstanceState add those id's to your savedInstanceState Bundle (using the putIntegerArrayList function so you don't have to save each id seperately)
- In onCreate just check if savedInstanceState is null or not
- If savedInstanceState is not null, get the id's from it and iterate over them creating an EditText for with each id (just like you would on a button press)
- That's all there is to it :)

Just as a tiny background information: When rotating the device, the Activity gets recreated which means all programmatically added Views are "gone" (since the layout is inflated again). But if you add those Views with their respective id again, the state is preserved.

Enough talking here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout lnrDynamicEditTextHolder;
    private EditText edtNoCreate;
    private Button btnCreate;
    private static final String KEY_IDS = "IDS";

    List<EditText> allEditText = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    ArrayList<Integer> allIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lnrDynamicEditTextHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrDynamicEditTextHolder);
        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        edtNoCreate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNoCreate);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            allIds = savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(KEY_IDS)

            for (int i=0;i<allIds.size();i++){
                EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(allIds.get(i));
                editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                allEditText.add(editText);
                lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);
            }
        }

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()>0 && parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString())!=0) {
                        if(edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length()==0){
                            edtNoCreate.setError("This Item Cannot be Empty");
                            return;
                        }
                        allEditText.clear();
                        lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.removeAllViews();

                        int length = parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString());

                        for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
                            EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                            editText.setId(allIds.size());
                            allIds.add(allIds.size());
                            editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            allEditText.add(editText);
                            lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    edtNoCreate.setError("This Item Cannot be Empty");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putIntegerArrayList(KEY_IDS, allIds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look into incorporating ViewModels in your applications. ViewModels can save the state of an activity or fragment from onDeviceConfigurationChange (besides other configuration changes). All you need to do is ask for whatever viewModel you want from ViewModelProviders().

[ViewModels in android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)